# Dudas al modelar una base de datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mariadb, modelorelacional

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de la creación de un sistema para una imprenta, pero estoy en una duda medio grande en el enfoque de la estructura de la base de datos.
Pasa que la imprenta hace varios tipos de productos y el cliente me pide tener un menú principal donde se listen los productos que hacen. Lo que no se es: Como hacer con las tablas pedidos cabecera y pedidos detalle. En la tabla pedidos_cabecera tengo el id, el cliente, la fecha y el estado. Y en la tabla pedidos_detalle tengo las propiedades de cada producto (y es aca donde se me complica la vida) Por ejemplo un talonario impreso tiene sus medidas, duplicado, triplicado etc. y un flyer tiene tipo de color, medidas(diferente al talonario) etc. Mi pregunta es: meto todas las propiedades de cada producto en la tabla pedidos_detalles o tengo que crear una tabla de productos con detalle_productos?
No se si me pude expresar de manera correcta, gracias.
[image: imagen_descriptiva]

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo el problema son las medidas ya que cada producto tiene sus propias caracteristicas.

creo que seria mas adecuado manejar la venta usando MongoDB u otra base de datos documental, esto debido al dinamismo de los productos.

otra opción es usar el tipo de dato JSON en [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/), por ejemplo:

Pedido_Detalle

```
- ped_det_id
- cantidad
- maquina_id
- pedido_id
- producto_id
- producto_detalle: JSON = {
  medida: "duplicado",
  hojas: 12
  ...,
 }
```

recuerda en el backend generar un esquema JSON para cada tipo de producto de esa forma sera mas simple mapear ese objecto guardado en BD.

algunas consideraciones son:

- FK `maquina_id` debería estar en la tabla pedidos
- la tabla `detalle_pedidos` solo debe contener FK de `producto_id`, `pedido_id` y el detalle de producto (ejemplo con tipo JSON).
- crear una tabla **tipo_producto** y asignar un FK en la tabla productos, de esta forma un producto estará asociado a un tipo que agrupe varios productos por ejemplo "papeleria" > "talonario", "resma", etc..

Espero que me hayas entendido y haber sido de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer mi problema y de contestar. Tomare en cuenta tu respuesta.

Comment: reescribi la respuesta ya que la encontré confusa

Comment: Gracias bucareyg!.